# Activiti BPMN Engine: store custom property in Database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, activiti, bpmn

i use the latest [Acitiviti 5.22.0](https://www.activiti.org/) engine (to be more concrete i use Alfresco Process Services 1.6.3) and i have implemented a Spring bean that gets executed every 10 minutes to generate a JSON representation of all my processes (process name, startDate, endDate, current taskName(s) and assignee(s)), to send them to an audit server. The problem is, that i only need to send all changed processes since the last run.

I do not want to send the JSON as soon as a process changes but to do a batch update of my audit system every 10 minutes.

To accomplish this, i've tried different approaches. My latest one:

1. Create a event listener bean that listens to all PROCESS_STARTED, PROCESS_COMPLETED, PROCESS_CANCELLED, TASK_COMPLETED, ...
2. Every time the event is triggered, store a process variable "_dirty" and set it to true
3. Every 10 minutes (wenn my JSON-bean is executed) query for all processes with the "_dirty" variable set to true
4. After sending the JSON to the audit system, set all "_dirty" process variables to false.

The problem with this approach: I am not able to update the "_dirty" variable after a process is ended. At least i don't know how.

My second approach would be to to store the processInstanceId on every event into a "global" property, but i don't know how to store this "global" property into database in case the server restarts. Is there a way to persist a property or an Entity into DB without creating an extra table, DAO, etc.?

Any ideas on how to solve this task? All tips are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, There's no such option

But you look at this. and see if it can be helpful in your case.
https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_database_tables

Answer (score 0):

As Linus suggested: This is not possible, so I needed some completely different approach.

I am creating an Ad-Hoc task now and store my properties as a local task variable. The Ad-Hoc task is owned by a system account and not assigned to anybody. This way I can make sure, no one of my real users tries to "complete" the task. Also I've written some code to generate the task if needed, so in case i want to clean it, it is created automatically the next time i want to store data.

Creating an Ad-Hoc task is quite easy by using org.activiti.engine.TaskService autowiring into my class.

```
Task task = taskService.newTask();
task.setDelegationState(DelegationState.PENDING);
task.setName("Some name goes here");
task.setTenantId("your tenant id (if any)");
task.setOwner("your system accounts ID");
task.setCategory("i use a special category to later query for the task");
taskService.saveTask(task);
```

After saving the task to the database, I can use the taskService to store and retrieve variables like this:

```
taskService.setVariableLocal(task.getId(), "variableKey", "variableValue");
```

Or query for the task like this:

```
Task task = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskDelegationState(DelegationState.PENDING).taskCategory("your special category").singleResult();
```

Not a very nice solution (I recommend having the task cached in a bean or something, so you don't need to query it all the time or even cache its values or something), but it works.